# Comparison of two tables

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables named **"rel_eq"** and **"rel_cat"**. From the table **"rel_cat"** I need to compare the id with the column **"relcat"** in the table **"rel_eq"**. And I need to select all columns from both tables so that I can output in a loop. In some lines in the **"rel_eq"** table, there is no value in the relcat column. I need to make sure there is either no value where it is missing, or a default, like "uncategory". My code `$eq_arr = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name CROSS JOIN $table_cat");` but I have to sort through all the id and assign the same id from another table. Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Hi. On stackoverflow, it does not work like this. You have to try and then to ask for help, presenting your code, so that we can correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to run the following:

```
$eq_arr = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM rel_eq join rel_cat on rel_eq.relcat = rel_cat.id");
```

If you want a record even when there is no match, use `INNER JOIN` and handle the problem in your cycle.